# Sprites cortados ou deslocados em telas com dpi alto

Tags: bug, status-pronto, design

#### Most sprites cropped, misplaced or deformed on high-resolution displays

The problem happens on any display with a pixel ratio of 1.5 or greater (like retina iPads, retina Macbook Pros, and other high-res displays. Even the site logo is affected (looks "squeezed", and actually looks better that way :)

I digged this deeper after reading this [duplicated bug-report](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/718/missing-images-on-badge3-class-on-badges-on-stackoverflow-in-portugues) once again, and also [this answer on the main site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9268/como-simular-uma-tela-de-maior-resolucao-para-verificar-o-comportamento-de-um-we). **The cause of the problem is a wrong value in the CSS for screens with a pixel ratios of 1.5 or greater**:

[image: inspeção do css no chrome]

The fix is a matter of replacing this:

```
background-size: 220px 500px;
```

with this:

```
background-size: 240px 500px;
```

---

Após o deploy das atualizações de ontem (2013-01-08), o site principal passou a apresentar uma série de problemas de layout no meu iPad com tela retina.

Diversos *sprites* parecem deslocados para a esquerda, em alguns casos de maneira bem visível (voto a favor clicado, medalhas), em outros de maneira mais sutil (setas não clicadas descentralizadas com o placar, ícones de sites descentralizados com a pontuação abaixo deles), como se pode ver nesta imagem:

[image: montagem com sprites deslocados]

Isso só acontece no site principal, no meta está tudo bem. E o problema só apareceu depois do deploy de ontem. Parece que algo mudou no CSS e/ou folha de *sprites*, e faltaram alguns ajustes para telas retina (se alguém puder confirmar se ocorre também em um MacBook retina, agradeço).

Comment: Também acontece comigo.

Comment: Destaquei uma explicação do problema em inglês para chamar a atenção dos desenvolvedores. Estou usando um laptop com tela de alta definição (227 dpi), e o problema acontece aqui também.

Comment: É fato. Nossos bug reports e feature-requests deveriam sempre que possível ter um sumário em Inglês. This bug really sucks :/

Comment: @brasofilo Veja a resposta do Gabe abaixo e meus comentário. A coisa é mais complicada do que eu achava.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agora sim o problema foi corrigido, tanto no site principal quanto no meta. Obrigado, Jin.

Comment: Quero chegar logo em casa para testar =]

Comment: @Math The bug is back! Noooooooooo!

Comment: :(​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 3):

## Please fix this on meta too!

As mentioned in the comments to Gabe's answer, this is not 100% fixed: **it's now okay in the main site, but wrong on meta.** Apparently both sites share the same CSS (do they really?), but the sprite images are different: [440 x 1000](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/content/brmeta/img/sprites@2.png?v=c051b78c88cf) on meta, and [480 x 1000](http://cdn.sstatic.net/br/img/sprites@2.png?v=0c9e455ec133) on the main site. So, we either need different `background-size` for each site, or same-sized images on both.

Comment: Indeed. I bought a new tablet these days so I could experience this issue too, I couldn't see this before. I'm glad you brought up this topic again. Hope someone fix it.

Comment: @Math, wait, `"bought [...] so I could experience this issue too"`, really? You just won a full year of free downvotes for your dedication to the site :D

Comment: @brasofilo thank you for recognizing my effort ;). But actually I might have not put the words correctly, what really happened is that I bought a tablet, period. I visited the site, period. I saw the faulty layout, that I couldn't see before, period. This topic came up again, right after I see the problem, period. I'm glad for it and I'm hopeful someone will fix it, period. I'm contacting some English schools for a few reinforcement classes.

Comment: You forgot to say "period" after the last sentence, @Math. :)

Comment: It's because I'm not done contacting English schools ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Embora eu ainda não tenha perdido as esperanças de ver isso consertado logo, criei um bookmarklet para quebrar o galho enquanto a solução definitiva não vem:

```
javascript:(function(){var stl = document.createElement('style'); stl.type="text/css"; var css = ".envelope-on, .envelope-off, .vote-up-off, .vote-up-on, .vote-down-off, .vote-down-on, .star-on, .star-off, .comment-up-off, .comment-up-on, .comment-flag, .edited-yes, .feed-icon, .vote-accepted-off, .vote-accepted-on, .vote-accepted-bounty, .badge-earned-check, .delete-tag, .grippie, .expander-arrow-hide, .expander-arrow-show, .expander-arrow-small-hide, .expander-arrow-small-show, .anonymous-gravatar, .badge1, .badge2, .badge3, #hlogo a, .gp-share, .fb-share, .twitter-share, #notify-container span.notify-close, .migrated.to, .migrated.from {background-size: 240px 500px !important;}"; stl.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));document.head.appendChild(stl);}());
```

Answer (score 1):

O Jin consertou o problema, usando a sugestão do @bfavaretto, inclusive. Vai pro ar no próximo build.

Comment: Viva o Jin! Viva!

Comment: Mas... Agora o problema veio pro meta, antes aqui não ocorria. Só que está ao contrário: no meta o logo está esticado, e os sprites estão deslocados para a direita, não para a esquerda. Pelo visto a coisa é mais complicada do que eu achava.

Comment: No meta, a imagem retina tem 440px de largura, e não 480. E a normal tem 220px de largura, enquanto no site principal tem 240. Pelo visto, a largura da imagem usada no meta também precisa ser ajustada, ou os dois sites não podem compartilhar essa parte do CSS.

Comment: Gabe, **please**, faz um *bump* desse problema (sprites falhando no meta) pros designers. Ou é melhor abrir um novo bug report?

Comment: Cada vez que venho no Meta com a tablet e vejo o design todo avacalhado por causa de um ajuste mínimo no CSS... :(

Comment: @brasofilo Postei outra resposta sobre isso (em inglês, pros devs poderem ver direto). Ia encher o saco do Gabe no chat dos moderadores, mas como ele deve ser notificado deste meu comentário, fica enchido aqui mesmo :)

Comment: @bfavaretto Vou falar com o Jin

Comment: @Gabe :( . . . . *Can you guys, **please**, fix this once and for all?* . . . .  Dá vontade de abrir uma duplicata do bug report só pra contrariar...

Comment: @brasofilo Já passei pros designers tem um tempo, mas não sei como está. Vou olhar