# Missing images on .badge3 class on Badges on StackOverflow in Português

Tags: bug, status-pronto, medalhas, design

There are missing images on badges (on retina displays):

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges

[image]

Should work with this in the css:

```
/*for silver badge*/
.badge1{background-position: -73px -400px;} 
/*for gold badge*/
.badge2{background-position: -91px -400px;width: 10px;}
/*for bronze badge*/
.badge3{background-position: -55px -400px;}
```

[image]

Comment: It seems to be the same issue I reported for the iPad here: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/454/ipad-diversos-sprites-aparecem-cortados-ou-deslocados?rq=1

Comment: I only saw this happening on iPad and iPhone retina displays, and I suspect a css media query issue. What kind of display are you using?

Comment: Weird, looks okay on the ipad now too. Don't know when it was fixed.

Comment: I was wrong, it's not solved. It happens on the main site, but not on meta.

Comment: @Sklivvz Is the fix supposed to be live yet? If it is, I'm afraid this is not status-complete. In this case, please see the "update" section [here](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/454) you have/had a typo in the CSS (bg size for the spritesheet should be `240`, not `220`).

Comment: @bfavaretto maybe it's caching? I see the correct images: http://i.stack.imgur.com/BYVvr.png

Comment: @Sklivvz It only happens on high-density displays (retina and the like). I don't think it's caching.

Comment: @Sklivvz, I second bfavaretto. Tried different browsers, clearing all browsing data. Bug still there.